# I created my own template, but how can I add the blogger lightbox function on my template code

Tags: templates, lightbox, blogger

I created my first blogger template from scratch; However, the lightbox function doesn't work.

When, I click a img on my post, it go to the img url. I tried to activate the lightbox property on configuration > post, comments and share, but it doesn't to anything.

Is their any way to add a code to my template to add the blogger lightbox function?

Comment: Add your code or url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an alternative for blogger lightbox which works perfectly and I think also better than blogger default lightbox

here is the link:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify are you using WordPress? If so then you may want to check the codex at https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development. Specifically for the item where you may need to use short codes such as:

PHP example: "echo do_shortcode('[*whatEverYourShortCodeIs*]');"

You may also need to call wp_head(); to enable plugins to work.

If it is not WP, then kindly post any other details up here as the community is quite helpful and I'm sure someone else would come along that may be able to help.

Comment: I said blogger, no wp

Answer (score 0):

Insert line `<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>` before `</head>`.